# WCF Converting Dictionary to JSon Array

Tags: json, wcf, dictionary

Why is WCF converting a Dictionary or Hashtable both, to an array of objects with Key/Value pairs? Is there a setting to fix this so the generated json object is a true javascript dictionary?

I should be able to do this with the resulting json object.

```
myObject["MyKey"]
```

The class:

```
[DataContract]
public class BasicData
{
    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Values { get; set; }
}
```

The output:

```
"Values":[{"Key":"Date","Value":"2012-06-20T17:37:46.48Z"}...]
```